# Parametros via xml para ImageView customizado

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

Tenho um `ImageView` customizado, que irá funcionar como um `Switch`.

Na tela, terei vários deste item, mas de cores diferentes.

Gostaria de saber se é possível passar um parametro de cor na declaração do xml.

Exemplo:

```
<com.example.utils.SwitchCustom
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp" 
        cordefundo="azul"/>
```

Obrigado!

Comment: você tentou android:background="@android:color/black" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É possível criar atributos customizados.
Par isso é necessário declarar um *Attribute Resource*:

Na pasta `res/value` crie um arquivo chamado `attrs.xml` com o seguinte conteúdo:

```
<resources>
   <declare-styleable name="SwitchCustom">
       <attr name="cordefundo" format="color" />
   </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

No código java do *SwitchCustom* poderá aceder ao valor desse atributo no construtor `SwitchCustom(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)`:

```
private int cordefundo;

public SwitchCustom(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
    super(context, attrs);

    TypedArray a = context.getTheme()
                          .obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.SwitchCustom, 0, 0);

    try {
        cordefundo = a.getInteger(R.styleable.SwitchCustom_cordefundo, 0);
    } finally {
        a.recycle();
    }
}
```

Ao inserir o *SwitchCustom* num *layout*, para ter acesso ao atributo, tem de indicar, no layout, o *namespace* a que ele pertence:

```
xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.example.utils"
```

Exemplo para um LinearLayout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.example.utils">

    <com.example.utils.SwitchCustom
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp" 
        custom:cordefundo="@android:color/blue"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado!